# Why i have this error in react webpack file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle

[image]

this error occurs only when the web pack mode is on development

I tried to insert an environment variable for node on the pc but it didn't work

Comment: undefined getCurrentStack error can be caused by trying to run the project in development mode when it was compiled in production mode.

Comment: Could you add source codes or share a jsfiddle link?